# What is the best relationship model for high performance?

Tags: oracle, database-design, optimization, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I want to model a relationship between Customer and Transaction.

However, because Customer is only described by a unique string and no extra info, I have two possibilities to implement it in the database:

```
Customer(Id, NameString) --> Transaction(CustomerId, OtherDetails...)
```

or

```
Transaction(CustomerNameAsString, OtherDetails...)
```

I have to manage a few hundreds transactions per sec, and store a several million transaction in the table.

Each new transaction `INSERT` is done after 1 or 2 `SELECT` queries on the table, like `SELECT count transactions (customer, lastMonth)`.

Is there a big performance penalty on one model or another?

In other words, what is the faster way?  Should I use a join and an integer index, or a string index with no join?

I am using Oracle.

Comment: I sure hope you're not expecting the customer's _name_ to be unique...

Comment: It's not a person name, but a unique system-allocated identifier, because my customers are machines.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to keep your transaction table as small as possible, so use an integer column as a foreign key to your customer table.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the size of the id is going to make _that_ big of a difference.  I'd probably go with a fk regardless (int or the actual id), just in case things have the possibility to change.